# Sorting an array of enumeration

Tags: c#

Hello I have an array of enumerations, and I'm trying sort that array by their enumeration value and get the array index's of the top

```
private enum Values
{
LOW,
MEDIUM,
HIGH
}

private Values[] Settings = new Values[10];
Settings[0] = LOW;
Settings[1] = HIGH;
Settings[2] = MEDIUM;
Settings[3] = LOW;
Settings[4] = LOW;
Settings[5] = LOW;
Settings[6] = LOW;
Settings[7] = LOW;
Settings[8] = MEDIUM;
Settings[9] = MEDIUM;
```

Basically now, with what I have above, I need to sort the settings array by enumeration value and get the array indexes of the top (let's say 3) items;

So I'd get back values 1, 2, 8

The platform I'm using does not support LINQ so those handy functions are not available.

I've been trying to wrap my head around this but it would help to have another pair of eyes.

thanks.

Comment: Sorry, yeah the editor cut off part of the opening description. That should say Top 3.

I am trying to get the top 3 highest values out of that array. Which - in the specific example - would be array indexes 1, 2, & 8.

Comment: Do you want the highest values or the indexes of those values? You could create a list or array to hold your results and then use a for or foreach loop to iterate over the list and collect your results. It might be your instructor wants you to create a sorting algorythm first and then collect the results (are you learning about bubble sort perhaps?).

Comment: What framework do you use? What _can_ you use if not LINQ?

Comment: That's not valid code... it should be `Settings[0] = Values.LOW;`

Comment: @Rufus L really besides the point. It's obvious what I'm trying to do there.

Comment: Basically, enumerations are ints, so it isn't different from doing the same with an int array

Comment: @Igor What instructor?

Comment: Its not really clear your intent. Sort the array and grab top 3. If you sorted that array, the top three would be the same values. If you are trying to run through the array and get the top 3 highest values, they would be the same as well. if you want the top 3 distinct highest values, then that is a different operation as well. Is your intent to sort, intent to get the top highest, highest distinct, all of the above?

Comment: @CodeMonkeyForHire The goal is to get the *indexes* of the top 3 values, not the values themselves.

Comment: Yeah i know it's clear what you're doing, but it's helpful if sample code compiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since you say you work in an environment where Linq is not available, I assume that other things like generics, nullables and so on will not be available either. A very low-tech solution.

Basic idea:

For every possible enum value, from highest to lowest, go through the list. If we find that value, output it and remember how many we have output. If we reach 3, stop the algorithm.

So, we first look for HIGH in the list, then for MEDIUM and so on.

```
class Program
{

    private enum Values
    {
        LOW,
        MEDIUM,
        HIGH
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Sample data
        Values[] settings = new Values[10];
        settings[0] = Values.LOW;
        settings[1] = Values.HIGH;
        settings[2] = Values.MEDIUM;
        settings[3] = Values.LOW;
        settings[4] = Values.LOW;
        settings[5] = Values.LOW;
        settings[6] = Values.LOW;
        settings[7] = Values.LOW;
        settings[8] = Values.MEDIUM;
        settings[9] = Values.MEDIUM;


        // Get Values of the enum type
        // This list is sorted ascending by value but may contain duplicates
        Array enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Values));

        // Number of results found so far
        int numberFound = 0;

        // The enum value we used during the last outer loop, so
        // we skip duplicate enum values
        int lastValue = -1;

        // For each enum value starting with the highest to the lowest
        for (int i= enumValues.Length -1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // Get this enum value
            int enumValue = (int)enumValues.GetValue(i);

            // Check whether we had the same value in the previous loop
            // If yes, skip it.
            if(enumValue == lastValue)
            {
                continue;
            }
            lastValue = enumValue;

            // For each entry in the list where we are searching
            for(int j=0; j< settings.Length; j++)
            {
                // Check to see whether it is the currently searched value
                if (enumValue == (int)settings[j])
                {
                    // if yes, then output it.
                    Console.WriteLine(j);
                    numberFound++;

                    // Stop after 3 found entries
                    if (numberFound == 3)
                    {
                        goto finished;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        finished: 

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output is as requested 1,2,8

Comment: The approach by @Efraim Newman might have a slightly better performance in some situations

Answer (score 3):

Implement a wrapper reference type,

```
class ValueWrapper : IComparable<ValueWrapper>
{
    public Values Value { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(ValueWrapper other)
    {
        return this.Value.CompareTo(other.Value) * -1; // Negating since you want reversed order
    }
}
```

Usage -

```
ValueWrapper[] WrappedSettings = new ValueWrapper[10];
for(int i = 0; i < WrappedSettings.Length; i++)
{
    WrappedSettings[i] = new ValueWrapper { Value = Settings[i], Index = i };
}
Array.Sort(WrappedSettings);
```

`WrappedSettings` will be sorted as you specified, preserving the indexes they were in the original array.

Comment: It makes sense to store the index and the value in a new type and do the comparison on that type, but the negation inside `CompareTo` is not in the right place. It is the caller's job to iterate forward or backwards. The negation would make sense only if was made by a comparer (i.e. `DescendingValueWrapperComparer : IComparer<ValueWrapper>`).

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
Values first = Values.Low,second = Values.Low,third = Values.Low;
int firstI = -1,secondI = -1, thirdI = -1;
for(int i = 0;i < Settings.Length;i++)
{
    if(Settings[i] > first || firstI == -1)
    {
        third = second;
        thirdI = secondI;

        second= first;
        secondI= firstI;

        first = Settings[i];
        firstI = i;
    } 
    else if(Settings[i] > second || secondI == -1)
    {
        third = second;
        thirdI = secondI;

        second = Settings[i];
        secondI = i;
    } 
    else if(Settings[i] > third || thirdI == -1)
    {
        third = Settings[i];
        thirdI = i;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want because it doesn't sort the original array, but one way to get the indexes of the top three values is to simply store the indexes of the top values in another array. Then we can loop through the original array, and for each item, see if it's larger than any of the items at the indexes we've stored so far. If it is, then swap it with that item.

For example:

```
// Start the topIndexes array with all invalid indexes
var topIndexes = new[] {-1, -1, -1};

for (var settingIndex = 0; settingIndex < Settings.Length; settingIndex++)
{
    var setting = Settings[settingIndex];
    var topIndexLessThanSetting = -1;

    // Find the smallest topIndex setting that's less than this setting
    for (int topIndex = 0; topIndex < topIndexes.Length; topIndex++)
    {
        if (topIndexes[topIndex] == -1)
        {
            topIndexLessThanSetting = topIndex;
            break;
        }

        if (setting <= Settings[topIndexes[topIndex]]) continue;

        if (topIndexLessThanSetting == -1 ||
            Settings[topIndexes[topIndex]] < Settings[topIndexes[topIndexLessThanSetting]])
        {
            topIndexLessThanSetting = topIndex;
        }
    }

    topIndexes[topIndexLessThanSetting] = settingIndex;
}

// topIndexes = { 1, 2, 8 }
```